# Laravel assets (bootstrap angularjs) bower or composer

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5, bower

I'm wondering what's the best way to use vendor packages in a laravel application by bower or composer ?

**UPDATE**

@Martin Bean
I always use bower for the assets
but I saw in this repo https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate 
like in composer.json

```
"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "illuminate/html" : "5.*",
        "laravel/socialite" : "~2.0",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "1.*",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "3.*",
        "twbs/bootstrap-sass": "3.*",
        "fortawesome/font-awesome": "4.*"
}
```

and here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap so my question

Answer (score 2):

They’re apples and oranges. Composer is for PHP packages, Bower is for front-end dependencies, like AngularJS, Bootstrap, jQuery etc.

Comment: Answer still stands. Composer shouldn’t be used to pull things like Bootstrap into your project.

Comment: I agree with you I don't like to mix up apples and oranges but I was curious about it :) btw thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Use [bower](http://bower.io/) for your javascript/css libraries and [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) for your php libraries.

Comment: @Whisher My answer still stands.